# Integration problems

Tags: integration, summation

Can anyone help me with these:-

(a)Prove by induction: $\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^nk^2 = \frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}$

(b) By explicitly calculating upper and lower Riemann sums on a uniform partition and
passing to the limits, calculate $\displaystyle\int_0^1 x^2 \mathrm{d}x$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Use $$\int_a^b f(x)dx=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{i=0}^n f\left(a+i\frac{b-a}{n}\right)\frac{b-a}{n}$$ Here $f(x)=x^2, a=0,b=1$ and so $$f\left(a+i\frac{b-a}{n}\right)=x^2\Big|_{x=0+\frac{i}n}=i^2/n^2$$ and so...

Comment: Great hint! $\;\;\bf + 1\;$

Answer (score 1):

The Riemann sum for that integral is

$$\frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{k^2}{n^2} = \frac{1}{n^3} \sum_{k=1}^n k^2$$

Apply the formula from part (a) and take the limit as $n \to \infty$.

For part (a), you need to show that

$$\frac{n(n+1) (2 n+1)}{6} + (n+1)^2 = \frac{(n+1)(n+2)(2 n+3)}{6}$$

Comment: @babak: I sit in wonder as to what I did to deserve your kindness.  Thanks!

Comment: Thanks Dear $\large{Count}$! :D

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Use part (a) to do part (b).

Answer (score 0):

$P(k)=\sum k^2=\dfrac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}$

Check for the base, $P(1)=\dfrac{1 \cdot 2 \cdot 3}{6}=1$

Assume $P(k)$ is true, $P(k)=\dfrac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}$

$P(k+1)=\sum (k+1)^2=\sum k^2+2k+1=\dfrac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}+2 \dfrac{n(n+1}{2}+n$.

You will see that its true. Finally you will get $\dfrac{(n+1)(n+2)(2n+3)}{6}$.

My $\sum$ means $\sum_1^n$